# How to properly associate a model with multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've tried to implement many of the proposed solutions in the relevant questions, but haven't yet found an answer ideal for what I'm trying to achieve in my Rails 4 application.

Basically my app has three models. Users, Hooks (embeddable pop-up widgets) and Contacts. Users can create Hooks and Contacts within their interface. And any visitor can create a new contact by filling out the Contact create form placed within a Hook's view, and that contact is associated with the user who created that hook.

That works fine, however when a contact is created by filling out a Hook's form, there's no connection to the specific Hook they completed the form in.

The next set of features I would like to add to my app requires not only associating each contact with a user, but also with the specific Hook it was created from.

I've read a bit into polymorphic associations (model belongs to multiple models) and I understand that's probably the way to go. After a couple of failed attempts, I'm not sure how to implement it though.

How would I associate Contacts with Hooks, so users can know which hook a contact was created from?

Here is what I currently have in the Hooks controller and model...

```
def create
    @hook = hook.new(hook_params)
    @hook.user = current_user
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @hook.save
        format.html { redirect_to @hook, notice: 'Hook was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @hook }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @hook.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

---

```
class Hook < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/app/assets/leadmagnet.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

---

And here is the contacts controller and model...

```
def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    @contact.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
    if @contact.save
          if user_signed_in?
            format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
          else
            format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
          end
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contact }
    else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
    end
  end
```

---

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :user
  validates :email, :presence => {:message => 'Email cannot be blank'}
end
```

Comment: What is the issue you are experiencing specifically?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not necessary, or especially desired to treat Stack Overflow like a social-site. SO is more of an online-reference, similar to Wikipedia, where things like "Hi and thanks in advance for any help regarding this obstacle I'm facing." and "Thanks for any help!" aren't really needed. Stick with writing well thought-out questions and you'll do great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should never ever ever create 2 unrelated models on the same controller action.  It breaks conventions and will only lead to problems.

You do not need to directly associate Contacts to Users.  You should associate Contacts to Hooks and then associate Contacts through Hooks

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :hooks
    has_many :contacts, through: :hooks
end

class Hook < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :contacts

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :hook
end
```

Now on the create action of the ContactsController, you can first get the Hook either by URL param or passed via post body.  You can first find the Hook and create the Contact on it via:

```
hook = Hook.find(hook_id)
@contact = hook.contacts.new(contacts_param)
```

If you want to create contacts when creating a new Hook, you need to add :contacts_attributes on the strong_params, then pass an array of contact attributes via the POST.  Adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to the Hook model allows you to easily create Contacts while creating Hooks by simply entering:

```
@hook = Hook.new(hook_params)
```

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need. Thanks. However after implementing your solution I'm getting this error...

**NameError at /contacts
undefined local variable or method "hook_id" for #<ContactsController:0x007fdab9da9300>**

Here's the hook controller's create action...

`def create
    hook = hook.find(hook_id)
    @contact = hook.contacts.new(contact_params)
    @contact.user = current_user`

Comment: You need to nest the Contacts routes within Hooks.  If you are creating a new Contact on a existing Hook, you would likely do so for a Hook #show view.  Therefore, your #create contact POST route should look like: `/hooks/:hook_id/contacts`.  See this page for more info:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.  Also, as I mentioned, there is no need to directly associate Contacts and Users as they will be associated through the Hook, so `@contact.user = current_user` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create both a `Hook` and a `Contact`, and associate both to `current_user`. In your code you create both, but you only associate `@hook` with the `current_user`, and only save it, while ignoring the `@contact`. Simply associate it and save it as well:

```
def create
    @hook = hook.new(hook_params)
    @hook.user = current_user
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    @contact.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @hook.save && @contact.save
        format.html { redirect_to @hook, notice: 'Hook was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @hook }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @hook.errors + @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Hi Uri and @brian-wheeler, thanks for answering so quickly. The issue I'm facing is associating contacts with hooks. That way hooks have contacts, and contacts can be associated with a specific hook.